# Технологии для создания клиента - (интернет-магазина) на андроид

Tags: android

Посоветуйте какие технологии почитать, для создания приложения (интернет магазин) - доска объявлений.
Просто стандартный набор компонентов в android studio мне кажется маловат для этого, и без костылей получится неотзывчивое приложение.